# set page template wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm writing a wordpress plugin but I can not set the page template manually (I mean **custom-page.php** or **thispage.php**) does anybody knows what is the function to use?

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template

or the helper function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_template

Comment: It suggest to use include. Do you think this is the better option?

Comment: Yeah especially if a user is using a parent and child theme. But you're right; you could just use include/require

Comment: But when i do it the default template is show after my template

Comment: remove everything from the default template; except the function